# Nginx to proxy SQL Database URL

Tags: sql-server, nginx, proxy

I have an SQL server with IP say 1.2.3.4. I also have an Nginx Server I use as a proxy server for creating subdomains and mapping them to other services I control however, I am unable to connect to my sql server using subdomain.

My Nginx site config is thus:

```
server {
    server_name mydb.domian.com;    

    location / {        
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4;
        proxy_set_header Host mydb.domian.com;
    } 

    server_name mydb.domian.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domian.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domian.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve by creating an A record with the desired subdomain (`mydb.domian.com`) which i mapped to the SQL server IP and it works fine.

Hope it helps someone in the future